# How do I speed up this program to find fibonacci sequence

Tags: c++, fibonacci, execution-time

I am doing this coding question where they ask you to enter numbers N and M, and you are supposed to output the Nth fibonacci number mod M. My code runs rather slowly and I would like to learn how to speed it up.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

long long fib(long long N) 
{ 
    if (N <= 1) 
        return N; 
    return fib(N-1) + fib(N-2); 
} 

int main () 
{ 
    long long N;
    cin >> N;
    long long M;
    cin >> M;
    long long b;
    b = fib(N) % M;
    cout << b; 
    getchar(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: dynamic programming - in order to not have to calculate the same numbers over and over again.

Comment: See Method 2: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/

Comment: You don't speed up *this* program. You write a *completely different* program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the program you wrote is pretty much the go-to example of recursion in education, it is really a pretty damn bad algorithm as you have found out. Try to write up the call tree for `fib(7)` and you will find that the number of calls you make balloons dramatically.

There are many ways of speeding it up and keeping it from recalculating the same values over and over. Somebody already linked to a bunch of algorithms in the comments - a simple loop can easily make it linear in N instead of exponential.

One problem with this though is that fibonacci numbers grow pretty fast: You can hold `fib(93)` in a 64 bit integer, but `fib(94)` overflows it.

However, you don't want the N'th fibonacci number - you want the N'th mod M. This changes the challenge a bit, because as long as M is smaller than MAX_INT_64 / 2 then you can calculate `fib(N) mod M` for any N.

Turn your attention to [Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) and the congruence relations. Specifically the one for addition, which says (changed to C++ syntax and simplified a bit):

If `a1 % m == b1` and `a2 % m == b2` then `(a1 + a2) % m == (b1 + b2) % m`

Or, to give an example: `17 % 3 == 2`, `22 % 3 == 1` => `(17 + 22) % 3 == (2 + 1) % 3 == 3 % 3 == 0`

This means that you can put the modulo operator into the middle of your algorithm so that you never add big numbers together and never overflow. This way you can easily calculate f.ex. `fib(10000) mod 237`.

Answer (score 1):

There is one simple optimatimization in calling fib without calculating duplicate values. Also using loops instead of recursion may speed up the process:

```
int fib(int N) {
    int f0 = 0;
    int f1 = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
         int tmp = f0 + f1;
         f0 = f1;
         f1 = tmp;
    }
    return f1;
}
```

You can apply the modulo operator sugested by @Frodyne on top of this.

Answer (score 0):

1st observation is that you can turn the recursion into a simple loop:

```
#include <cstdint>

std::uint64_t fib(std::uint16_t n) {
    if (!n)
        return 0;
    std::uint64_t result[]{ 0,1 };
    bool select = 1;
    for (auto i = 1; i < n; ++i , select=!select)
    {
        result[!select] += result[select];
    };
    return result[select];
};
```

next you can memoize it:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

std::uint64_t fib(std::uint16_t n) {
    static std::vector<std::uint64_t>  result{0,1};
    if (result.size()>n)
        return result[n];
    std::uint64_t back[]{ result.crbegin()[1],result.back() };
    bool select = 1;
    result.reserve(n + 1);
    for (auto i=result.size(); i < result.capacity();++i, select = !select)
        result.push_back(back[!select] += back[select]);
    return result[n];
};
```

Another option would be an algebraic formula.

cheers,
FM.